# When making php.ini recursive I get Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress site.

I am using php.ini to prepend a file.

```
auto_prepend_file = "/home/username/public_html/mysite/includes/prepend.php"
```

I now need to make this php.ini file recursive so it applies to all subdirectories. When I add the following line to my .htaccess

```
suPHP_ConfigPath /home/username/public_html/mysite
```

I get the following error message

```
Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.
```

If I remove the line from .htaccess I am able to access my site.

It seems that when I make the php.ini file recursive it breaks wordpress.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check your Apache error log?

Comment: Using cPanel? When I looked up "suPHP_ConfigPath wordpress" there is an article from cPanel that says to remove that from your htaccess

Comment: https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/360056355754-Your-PHP-installation-appears-to-be-missing-the-MySQL-extension-which-is-required-by-WordPress-

Comment: @Daantje I didn't check the error log. I will do that. Thanks.

Comment: @Jesse Thank you for linking the article. It describes my issue exactly. So it seems I can't make php.ini recursive within my file structure. I will try with .user.ini Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP here.

I ended up using `.user.ini` to prepend the file.

`.user.ini` is recursive. I created it inside the root of my website and it worked for all subdirectories.

**Solution that worked for me:**

(1) Removed the line `suPHP_ConfigPath /home/username/public_html/mysite` from `.htaccess`

(2) Created a `.user.ini` inside the root of my website and added the line

```
auto_prepend_file = "/home/username/public_html/mysite/includes/prepend.php"
```